# Plural noun with singular to be

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verbs, informal-language, linking-verbs

Let's consider such a dialog on a social network:

> "Yesterday a guy sent me a photo of his unshaven legs!"
>
> "Oh, legs **is/are** just a stupidity, it could've been much worse."

Can I reply like this and should it be *is* or *are*?

Comment: If it were a text, I think 'Oh, "legs" is just.. ' is fine.

Comment: What do you convey by this?

Comment: @SovereignSun that sending a pic of one's legs is just a manifestation of stupidity and isn't the worst possible scenario.

Comment: As SovereignSun mentions, the expression "to be a stupidity" sounds off in English no matter how the "to be" is inflected.

Comment: "Legs **are** just a stupidity.

Comment: Agreed about "stupidity", yes, I suppose it could be a countable noun, but using "a stupidity" to mean "something in particular that is stupid" sounds slightly wrong.

Comment: @stangdon I thought so. Comments section isn't the best place to ask this, but how would you call a foolish act or a particular manifestation of stupidity, then?

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer your first question - **Yes**, you can reply in whatever way you like!

To answer your second question - The whole phrase sounds awkward. I would personally use **"is"** to emphasize the *"is nothing but"*, however, it would be best if you rephrased the sentence:

- "Oh, legs. That's stupid. Yet, it could've been much worse."

Comment: P.s. I hate such photos.